# Reference an array item in Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I've a json that's being created from a CSV that looks like this,

```
[["Year","Make","Model","Description","Price"],["1997","Ford","E350","ac, abs, moon","3000.00"],["1999","Chevy","Venture \"Extended Edition\"","","4900.00"],["1999","Chevy","Venture \"Extended Edition, Very Large\"","","5000.00"],["1996","Jeep","Grand Cherokee","MUST SELL!\nair, moon roof, loaded","4799.00"]]
```

I need to use this in template using Handlebars.js, I know when to use this when the json was like this

```
[{"data" : "data1"},{.....}]
```

but doesn't know how to use handlebars when the json looks like the one I've been given at the begning, when I tried the following code,

```
        {{#each this}}
        <li>{{0}}</li>
        {{/each}}
```

I get the following error at the console

```
Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 3:
...}            <li>{{0}}</li>           
----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', 'DATA', got 'NUMBER'
```

Anyway to access the json data for the templating, is the error at the template or the json? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it with a square brackets:

```
<ul>
  {{#each this}}
    <li>{{[0]}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/teduxeduvoqi/1/edit

---

A quote from [the docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html):

> To reference a property that is not a valid identifier, you can use segment-literal notation, `[`

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this: `{{this[0]}}`.